# Unable to update key in kaspersky

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to update the key of Kaspersky End Point 8 Security using this command:

```
opt/kaspersky/kes4lwks/bin/kes4lwks-control -L --install-active-key <key_file_name>
```

But this gave the following error:

> bash syntax error near unexpected token 'newline'

Why do I get this error, and what should I do to correct it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are trying to execute precisely this command including the literal string `<key_file_name>`. The `<...>` notation usually means that you have to substitute this token. In this particular case, with your key file name. And another issue with this command line: you probably need leading `/` (`/opt/kaspersky/...`) because this path should be absolute, not relative to your current working directory. So the final command line should look similar to

`/opt/kaspersky/kes4lwks/bin/kes4lwks-control -L --install-active-key /home/user/kes.key`

PS: I do not know the syntax of this particular KES command, I just commented on general shell command syntax.

Comment: Dear Anatoly thank you for answering the question but i have not used the <key_file_name> literally instead i have placed my key in the stated slot and i have completely used the format that you define above now its saying " No such directory found" even though directory is there ???

Comment: @Malik could you please check that `wc -c /path/to/your/key` executes without error (it should print a number and a filename). Use the same strings that you have used in the command (it would be even better to take command from the bash history, delete irrelevant parts and prepend with wc -c). Then do the same with path to kes4lkws-control. In case of any errors please do not forget to replace any sensitive information such as serial numbers with some placeholder before pasting here.